# How do I make a window inactive on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to create an C++ console app that shows itself when I press a button. However, when the app appears, it appears on top of all other windows. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening (i.e. have the window appear in the background)?

Here is the part of the code that is important:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
//stuff happens
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOW);
```

When the window is shown, it does so in front of all other windows (which I don't want).
Here is an image of this behavior:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) in place of `ShowWindow`, specifying the `SWP_SHOWWINDOW`, `SWP_NOZORDER`, `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER`, and `SWP_NOACTIVATE` flags. This will show the window, without moving it up or down the Z order, or activating it.

Comment: If it's a console app though you can't stop the window from opening automatically can you? Unless you launch it from another app and use the `STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow` field to make it open hidden I guess.

Comment: @jon I was addressing the *"part of the code that is important"*, as spelled out in the question. If you are launching a process, you only get to choose between show or hide.

Comment: Ah I hadn't read that bit, it must have been added in after I first read the question. In that case wouldn't `SW_SHOWNA` work?

Comment: @JonathanPotter that didn't work, it seemed to have done the same as `SW_SHOW`